# Is there an HTML5 interface to the android or ios keyboard?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, html, mobile

I am trying to display a list of custom suggestions for the mobile keyboard input. Is it even possible to access a keyboard standard from within the browser using javascript?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to access the standard keyboard suggestions. If you want you could create your own version and disable the default suggestions. You could use the `onkeydown` event with returns values 65-90 for A-Z. With the following code you could determine what key is being pressed down and add that to some kind of `AJAX` query to request values from database using a web service. Using that data you could display a nicely formatted list that 
displays all the values.

```
document.onkeydown = function (){ 
    switch(event.keyCode.charAt) { 
        case 65:   // Starts With A   
        break;
        case 66:   // Starts With B   
        break;
        // Do other Case Statements
        default:   // Code to be executed if keyCode is different from A and B 
    } 
}
```

Comment: I don't understand how AJAX has anything to do with this. I want to be able to edit the list of suggestions of whichever keyboard app the phone uses; that's why I ask if there is some kind of standard api implemented for mobile javascript. Are you saying that this is not possible with just javascript?

Comment: You can't change the default list of suggestions, you can only give your own interface and disable the default. That is why I'm saying if you need to give certain options for the autocorrection, you should get your own values off of a server running a web service and database. You could also just create a local array, which isn't as easy to change.